# JS - Iterate through text snippet character by character, skipping certain characters

Tags: javascript, for-loop, character

I am using JS to loop through a given text, refered to in below pseudo as **"input_a"**.

Based on the contents of another, and seperate text **"input_b"** I would like to manipulate the individual characters of text **"input_a"** by assigning them with a boolean value.

So far I've approached it the following way:

```
for (i=0; i < input_a.length; i++) {
    if (input_b[i] == 0){
      //do something to output
    }
}
```

Now the issue with this is that the above loop, being that it uses .length also includes all blank/special characters whereas I would only like to include A-Z - ommitting all special characters (which in this case would not be applicable to recieve the boolean assigned to them).

How could I approach this efficiently and elegantly - and hopefully without reinventing the wheel or creating my own alphabet array?

*Edit 1: Forgot to mention that the position of the special characters needs to be retained when the manipulated **input_a** is finally delivered as output. This makes an initial removal of all special characters from input_a a non viable option.*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `input_a` to retain only alphabetical characters - you can transform it easily with a regular expression. Match all non-alphabetical characters, and replace them with the empty string:

```js
const input_a = 'foo_%%bar*&#baz';
const sanitizedInputA = input_a.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, '');
console.log(sanitizedInputA);
// iterate through sanitizedInputA
```

If you want the do the same to happen with `input_b` before processing it, just use the same `.replace` that was used on `a`.

If you need the respective indicies to stay the same, then you can do a similar regular expression test while iterating - if the character being iterated over isn't alphabetical, just `continue`:

```js
const input_a = 'foo_%%bar*&#baz';
for (let i = 0; i < input_a.length; i++) {
  if (!/[a-z]/i.test(input_a[i])) continue;
  console.log(input_a[i]);
}
```

Comment: That will mess up the indexes, he used `input_b[i]` in his example.

Comment: Also see above edit of original question, where the non A-Z characters needs to be retained for the final output. (e.g only skipped in the 'boolean' assignment').

Answer (score 0):

*Edited as per Edit 1 of PO*

If you would like to do this without RegEx you can use this function:

```
function isSpecial(char) {
    if(char.toLowerCase() != char.toUpperCase() || char.toLowerCase.trim() === ''){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then call this function for each character as it comes into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the character at the current position is a letter, something like:

```
for (i=0; i < input_a.length; i++) {
    if(/[a-z]/i.test(input_a[i])){
        if (input_b[i] == 0){
           //do something to output
        }
    }
}
```

the `/[a-z]/i` regex matches both upper and lower case letters.